# Cannot refer to a non-final variable db inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for Android but I got stuck on deleting things from my database!
I'm getting an "Cannot refer to a non-final variable db inside an inner class defined in a different method" error! I know what this error means but I can't seem to find a solution to this.

Here is my code

```
package iwt.ehb.be.capita_selecta;

//my imports

public class RemoveActivity extends Activity {

    Context context = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remove_activity);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllTrips();

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_removeTrips);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

            do {
                Button buttonView = new Button(this);
                buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.btn_blue);
                buttonView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                buttonView.setText(c.getString(1) + " @ " + c.getString(2));
                final int id_trip = c.getInt(0);
                buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        System.out.println(id_trip);

                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Attention");
                        alert.setMessage("Do you wish to delete this trip?");
                        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                db.deleteSpecificRecord(id_trip);
                            }
                        });
                        alert.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
                layout.addView(buttonView);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        //*******************
        //BACK-button
        //*******************   

        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the error at this line of code `db.deleteSpecificRecord(id_trip);`

If you have any idea on how I can resolve this that would be awsome ;)

Thx 
Kevin

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Attention");
```

context is a variable from the outer class. Variables like these can only be accessed if they are final.

There are a few possible fixes.
The first one is let your activity implement the onclicklistner

`Public class RemoveActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { ...
buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);`
imho the best solution

Another fix is make the variable context make a constructor with the following code:

```
Public RemoveActivity (){ this.context = this;}
```

but this is ugly code

i also think changing the line to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(RemoveActivity.this).setTitle("Attention");
```

would work.

Comment: or you can simply call as `AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setTitle("Attention");` . Putting the full stacktrace could be more useful as problem may be from somewhere else :)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but that isn't my problem. I said that i'm getting the error at "db.deleteSpecificRecord(id_trip);" if I comment out this line of code everything is working fine. When I try removing the comment then db gets underlined in red and saying my problem is "Cannot refer to a ..."

Comment: Well the story is about the same. You can't access it because you are in an inner class, so you can't reach variables from that class. OnClickListener is an interface whose abstract method you are implementing. It isn't allowed to mess with the db variable because it is in RemoveActivity. Either just do what he says and make it a final variable or make RemoveActivity implement the interface. Then just create a db field in the RemoveActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error . The thing with this is that java  treats each function with an independent scope . I see that you have declared the db Adapter object inside the on Create function . Take the declaration and declare it before the on create function ( rather extending the scope ) this should solve the problem . Your code should look like this :)

```
public class RemoteActivity extends Activity{
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
Context context = this;

onCreate () ...
```